# How to use broadcasting to speed up this code?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the following multi-dimensional array. The first axis denotes a
3-dimensional vector. I want to calculate the 3-by-3 matrix x⋅x' for each of
those.

My current solution:

```
arr.shape
# (3, 64, 64, 33, 187)

dm = arr.reshape(3,-1)
dm.shape
# (3, 25276416)

cov = np.empty((3,3,dm.shape[1]))
cov.shape
# (3, 3, 25276416)
```

this for-loop iterates over all 25,276,416 elements and takes around 1 or 2 min.

```
for i in range(dm.shape[1]):
    cov[...,i] = dm[:,i].reshape(3,1).dot(dm[:,i].reshape(1,3))

cov = cov.reshape((3,) + arr.shape)
cov.shape
# (3, 3, 64, 64, 33, 187)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not really reducing any axes with that matrix-multiplication using `np.dot` and it's just broadcasted elementwise multiplication there. So, you can simply use `NumPy broadcasting` for the whole thing, like so -

```
cov = dm[:,None]*dm
```

Or use it directly on `arr` to avoid creating `dm` and all that reshaping, like so -

```
cov = arr[:,None]*arr
```